# Need help with fixing JVC AX-311 amplifier

Tags: amplifier, repair, stereo

Electronics repair noobie here. I have tried to find the answer myself, but would like some assurance on this problem.

The left channel of my JVC AX-311 amplifier is unstable, it sometimes works, and sometimes it doesn't. Often when higher volume is asked of the channel, the sound cracks a little bit and them pops in, only to lose the signal again when the volume lowers. Someone told me that it could be an old soldering point that is deteriorated and that I should look on the printboard for soldering points that look cracked. So I did find something on my board (see pictures). Before I start I would like some help. How likely is it that this is causing the problem, should I look up the circuit schematic (I already did, but the schematic is too complex for me to understand myself) and if unlikely, how should I proceed to find the problem?

As you can see the two large solders above the three openings seem to have a circle around them where contact is broken

[image: as you can see the two large solders above the three openings seem to have a circle around them where contact is broken]

[image]

[image]

Comment: That solder joint looks bad. I would re-solder it and clean all the flux residue around with isopropyl alcohol. Generally, repair questions are off-topic here.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will try and do that. Need to buy some isopropyl alcohol first then. I did not know that repair questions are off topic here. Also apologies for the off-topic post. What is the correct place to ask such questions?

Comment: The solder joints themselves look okay, but there's a ton of excess flux there. @LiorBilia Repair questions are not off-topic, they just require a good amount of detail about the problem, and that the question is more than just "fix this for me". If Jozef adds the schematic they say they've found, that would be a good step towards making it more on-topic.

Comment: If in doubt, resoldering it or replace it - looks like there’s the same device for the other channel nearby. Have you confirmed it is part of the channel exhibiting the problem?  If it is a dodgy solder joint you should be able to tap the circuit board in a number of places with the butt end of a screwdriver.

Comment: Unlikely that these solder joints have anything to do with the issue. The large joints are unconnected and likely are heat sink legs, but do verify it yourself. I'd simply clean the volume pots and maybe signal relays have oxidized. Sometimes amps have channels at low volume until you turn the volume knob up, and that makes the signal to break through an oxidized contact, whether a relay, switch, volume knob etc.

Answer (score 1):

Visual heat darkening is of concern but can also lead you astray. Black charring is a definite red-flag.

You might measure Q801 emitter "E" with a DC voltmeter - it should be near +15V above GND.  It is a DC voltage regulator control element. Discoloured solder connections might not indicate a problem since this device has a heat sink - the designers expected it to run warm. Heat can darken rosin solder flux over time - the metal solder itself looks OK to me.

A more common problem with intermittent volume centers around the volume control potentiometer (front panel) itself - over time, it is exercised a lot. They can get scratchy. If tapping them changes sound quality or volume, this may be your problem.
You might also try re-seating each cable connector that runs between printed circuit boards.
Good luck - intermittent problems are a repair nightmare and can require much patience.

Comment: I have measured the emitter, and is indeed 15 V, so it appears fine. Didn't do much about the solders, but checked a couple of things with the multimeter, wiggled the cable connectors, and then screwed it back together. For now the intermittent problem appears to be on the positive side. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

From your description of the problem, this sounds entirely like a faulty volume potentiometer. They always get scratchy with age; spray some contact cleaner in there and turn it all the way to both ends a few times and see if that fixes it. You could also look into replacing the pot, but usually contact cleaner is all you need and stereo pots like this probably uses are a little hard to find these days.

---

As for the solder joints you've zoomed in on, you're chasing a red herring here. The solder joints you're looking at look perfectly fine, just a bit ugly with flux residue. (That solidified flux residue will probably come off if you gently chip at it, then just wipe the dust off with some isopropanol or soap and water.) The two that are visibly unconnected are just mechanical anchors for the heatsink; they're not meant to be electrically connected to anything.

There is a bit of darkening near the base terminal that suggests something's gotten hot right there, but it could also just be solidified flux residue and not the PCB itself darkening (which happens when exposed to high temperature over a long period of time). If it is thermal darkening, I couldn't say whether it needs to be addressed; you say this unit has been repaired before, and it's possible the earlier repair already fixed that problem. (The darkening is permanent, but doesn't in itself affect operation.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. From all the comments I also think it is a red herring. After tinkering a bit, it somehow seems to be functional again for the time being.

Comment: @Jozef I still recommend cleaning the potentiometer--you can do that without even opening the thing up, most likely; just pull the knob off (might have to undo a set screw) and spray a little bit of contact cleaner in around the potentiometer shaft, then move it back and forth a few times.

Answer (score 0):

The solder joints you describe are not connected on the PCB.  They are apparently for mechanical purposes, likely holding the heatsink for Q801.  Speaking of which: I don't like its solder points, particularly the middle one.  It looks like the focus of a previous repair by someone other than the god of solder.  Possibly using solder not best suited for electronics.

But it's a bit hard to tell because the image is out of focus.

Comment: I have added a picture that is better focused on this exact solder joint. The device has been to a repair shop in the past, for the same problem, only I don't remember if it was the right or left channel back then that was the problem. But looking at these solder joints, they probably did something here during the repair process. I think that I will try if re-soldering the PCB-connected solder joints solves the issue. Otherwise, could it be that the Q801 (D2061 transistor) is broken and needs to be replaced?

Comment: Well, the problem is intermittent operation.  That's not a sign of a "broken" transistor unless we are talking about a broken pin.  In-focus the joints don't seem like an immediate suspect even though I'd lean towards reflowing them myself since I think I can do better.  Depends on your soldering skills whether that is likely to be an (mostly aesthetic I guess) improvement.